# Why my UPnP device doesn't return services registered in UPnP SCPD xml file?

Tags: windows, delphi, upnp

I register a UPnP device with:

```
var o: IUPnPRegistrar;
    W: string;
    R: HRESULT;
begin
  w := TFile.ReadAllText('UPnPDevice_Desc.xml');
  o := CoUPnPRegistrar.Create as IUPnPRegistrar;
  R := o.RegisterDevice(w, ...);
end;
```

File UPnPDevice_Desc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
<specVersion>
    <major>1</major>
    <minor>0</minor>
</specVersion>

<device>
    <pnpx:X_deviceCategory xmlns:pnpx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pnpx/2005/11">Other</pnpx:X_deviceCategory>
<!--<pnpx:X_hardwareId xmlns:pnpx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pnpx/2005/11">Microsoft/SampleDevice/10000/urn:microsoft-com:device:SampleDimmerDevice:1</pnpx:X_hardwareId>-->
<!--    <df:X_containerId xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2008/09/devicefoundation">{8C7B310D-90F8-40D4-B5EA-71D81821DEA6}</df:X_containerId>-->
    <deviceType>urn:example-com:device:uPnPDevice:1</deviceType>
    <friendlyName>My UPNP Device Hosted by Windows</friendlyName>
    <manufacturer>Example Company</manufacturer>
    <manufacturerURL>http://www.example.com/</manufacturerURL>
    <modelDescription>My UPnP Device</modelDescription>
    <modelName>uPnPDevice</modelName>
    <modelNumber>1001</modelNumber>
    <modelURL>http://www.example.com/</modelURL>
    <serialNumber>123456</serialNumber>
    <UDN>uuid:RootDevice</UDN>
    <UPC>00000-00001</UPC>

    <serviceList>
      <service>
        <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SwitchPower:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower:1</serviceId>
        <controlURL></controlURL>
        <eventSubURL></eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>UPnPDevice_SCPD.xml</SCPDURL>
      </service>
    </serviceList>

    <presentationURL>DimmerPresentation.htm</presentationURL>
</device>
</root>
```

File UPnPDevice_SCPD.xml:

```
<scpd xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service-1-0">
<specVersion>
    <major>1</major>
    <minor>0</minor>
</specVersion>
<actionList>
    <action>
        <name>MagicOn</name>
    </action>
</actionList>
<serviceStateTable>
    <stateVariable>
        <name>OSMajorVersion</name>
        <dataType>i4</dataType>
    </stateVariable>
    <stateVariable>
        <name>OSMinorVersion</name>
        <dataType>i4</dataType>
    </stateVariable>
    <stateVariable>
        <name>OSBuildNumber</name>
        <dataType>i4</dataType>
    </stateVariable>
    <stateVariable>
        <name>OSMachineName</name>
        <dataType>string</dataType>
    </stateVariable>
</serviceStateTable>
</scpd>
```

I can confirm the UPnP device has been hosted in UPnP device host service by using IUPnPDeviceFinder or M-SEARCH to find the device.

The registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UPnP Device Host\Description
```

also contain the corresponding information:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UPnP Device Host\Description\{00BB4949-F3B2-4F5A-B534-C6FE61B71F4E}]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UPnP Device Host\Description\{00BB4949-F3B2-4F5A-B534-C6FE61B71F4E}\Files]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UPnP Device Host\Description\{00BB4949-F3B2-4F5A-B534-C6FE61B71F4E}\Files\{B11E040A-6858-48BA-B1BD-85B4E8FCBA73}]
"Filename"="M:\\uPNP\\D16\\Win32\\Debug\\UPnPDevice_SCPD.xml"
"Mimetype"="text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UPnP Device Host\Description\{00BB4949-F3B2-4F5A-B534-C6FE61B71F4E}\UDN Mappings]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UPnP Device Host\Description\{00BB4949-F3B2-4F5A-B534-C6FE61B71F4E}\UDN Mappings\uuid:RootDevice]
@="uuid:00bb4949-f3b2-4f5a-b534-c6fe61b71f4e"
```

When query for services of the UPnP device using

```
var Enum: IEnumVARIANT;
    Fetched: Cardinal;
    K: OleVariant;
    P: IUPnPService;
    W: WideString;
    D: IUPnPDevice
begin
  ...
  if D.Services.Count > 0 then begin
    Enum := D.Services._NewEnum as IEnumVARIANT;
    Enum.Reset;
    while Enum.Next(1, K, Fetched) = S_OK do begin
      P := IDispatch(K) as IUPnPService;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The D.Services.Count is 1 but the Enum doesn't fetch any services.  Variable Fetched always return 0.

If I have query for Media Player UPnP device, It did return the services available.

Any ideas what's wrong with my UPnP Device that doesn't return services as indicated in SCPD xml file?

Once I registered the device, the XML description will change to:

```
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>

    <device>
        <pnpx:X_deviceCategory xmlns:pnpx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pnpx/2005/11">Other</pnpx:X_deviceCategory>
<!--
<pnpx:X_hardwareId xmlns:pnpx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pnpx/2005/11">Microsoft/SampleDevice/10000/urn:microsoft-com:device:SampleDimmerDevice:1</pnpx:X_hardwareId>
-->
<!--
<df:X_containerId xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2008/09/devicefoundation">{8C7B310D-90F8-40D4-B5EA-71D81821DEA6}</df:X_containerId>
-->
        <deviceType>urn:example-com:device:uPnPDevice:1</deviceType>
            <friendlyName>My UPNP Device Hosted by Windows</friendlyName>
            <manufacturer>Example Company</manufacturer>
            <manufacturerURL>http://www.example.com/</manufacturerURL>
            <modelDescription>My UPnP Device</modelDescription>
            <modelName>uPnPDevice</modelName>
            <modelNumber>1001</modelNumber>
            <modelURL>http://www.example.com/</modelURL>
            <serialNumber>123456</serialNumber>
            <UDN>uuid:9742f52d-f39f-4eaf-9ecf-bb742e9d79e9</UDN>
            <UPC>00000-00001</UPC>
            <serviceList>
                <service>
                    <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SwitchPower:1</serviceType>
                    <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower:1</serviceId>
                    <controlURL>
                        /upnphost/udhisapi.dll?control=uuid:9742f52d-f39f-4eaf-9ecf-bb742e9d79e9+urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower:1
                    </controlURL>
                    <eventSubURL>
                        /upnphost/udhisapi.dll?event=uuid:9742f52d-f39f-4eaf-9ecf-bb742e9d79e9+urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower:1
                    </eventSubURL>
                    <SCPDURL>
                        /upnphost/udhisapi.dll?content=uuid:40c39217-e93b-4d0a-b5e0-abc582b2a2ed
                    </SCPDURL>
                </service>
            </serviceList>
        <presentationURL>
            /uuid:9742f52d-f39f-4eaf-9ecf-bb742e9d79e9/DimmerPresentation.htm?/upnphost/udhisapi.dll?content=uuid:9742f52d-f39f-4eaf-9ecf-bb742e9d79e9+uuid:9742f52d-f39f-4eaf-9ecf-bb742e9d79e9
        </presentationURL>
    </device>
</root>
```

Note the controlURL, eventSubURL and SCPDURL has been changed.  Accessing

```
http://localhost:2869/upnphost/udhisapi.dll?content=uuid:40c39217-e93b-4d0a-b5e0-abc582b2a2ed
```

return exact content as file UPnPDevice_SCPD.xml.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a Delphi problem instead of UPnP problem? I don't know Delphi, but if `D.Services.Count` says 1, how then you can't fetch anything? Even if null or invalid object? Does the `Enum` has count 1 too, before you start iterating it? I have some vague ideas what might be wrong with your SCPD, but the reported enumeration behavior is suspicious.

Comment: I also don't know why I can't fetch service item.  The Enum don't have count property.  Can you point to me what's wrong with my SCPD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SCPD document must add XML declration. e.g.: `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<scpd xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service-1-0">
...
</scpd>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have validated your XMLs against Device and Service XSDs and they have no problem. I recommend checking your running SwitchPower device with an external tool like [Intel Device Spy](http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp), to find out whether your SCPD is really served by the device. I am somewhat suspicious about `SCPDURL` not being prepended with a slash. Per DeviceArchitecture it "MUST be relative to the URL at which the device description is located" so if it doesn't start with slash, some funny URL might be constructed. That way you indeed get a Service (because Device description mentions it) but it can't obtain any information about it, so you might get some sort of invalid initialization. Just a theory. This all depends on those IUPnP* implementations i know nothing about.

Second thought, SwitchPower has several REQUIRED functions which you are not specifying in the SCPD. But that might not be an issue as long as you are not (yet) trying to access the service in a standard way.

Comment: I don't have any hardware device.  I am doing a pure software UPnP device.  The device is hosted in Windows UPnP device host service, a service where Windows Media Player is hosted.  The SwitchPower SCPD is only a sample XML.  I just want to test if I able to export the services out from my device DLL.

Comment: I have edited my question to add what I have found: once I register the device, the device description content changed.  The SCPDURL change to something like: /upnphost/udhisapi.dll?content=uuid:40c39217-e93b-4d0a-b5e0-abc582b2a2ed.  Access the SCPDURL from the web browser return exact content of my SCPD XML.  The IUPnPDevice.services.Count return 1 but I am not able to enumerate the services using IEnumVariant.

Comment: I found the problem, I must add <?xml version="1.0"?> in front of SCPD document.  I answer in another reply.

Comment: Glad that you found the problem. But i didn't talk about hardware device, ever. WMP is not a hardware device either and still is visible in the listing of Device Spy. UPnP doesn't know and doesn't care if your device is in hardware or in software. Your SwitchPower still should be visible in the Device Spy, if you aim for a valid service.